# Combine lists that have at least one item in common

Tags: groovy

I have a list of lists in groovy. Some of the nested lists have certain items in common. I would like for all of the nested lists that have at least one item in common to join into one list, for example:

Extract of my list of lists :

```
[[buy, order, bought, purchase],
 [opinion, point of view],
 [opinion, belief],
 [buy, purchased],
 [buy, order, purchases]]
```

(The order of nested lists is random)

What I would like to achieve :

```
[[buy, order, bought, purchase, buy, purchased, buy, order, purchases], 
 [opinion, point of view, opinion, belief]]
```

Anybody has any suggestions on how to achieve this?
Thank you!

Comment: of course you have tried to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, I have. But since my 'solutions' were so far from working, I didn't think it would help anybody if I published them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following with `inject`:

```
def input = [['buy', 'order', 'bought', 'purchase'],
             ['opinion', 'point of view'],
             ['opinion', 'belief'],
             ['buy', 'purchased'],
             ['buy', 'order', 'purchases']]

input.inject([]) { list, current ->
    list.find { it.intersect(current) }?.addAll(current) ?: list << current
    list
}
```

So, find an element in the output list that intersects with the current input list, and if it exists add it to that output list.

If one isn't found, add the input list to the output list

Comment: @zivuska cool! Could you accept it as an answer if it answered your question?